# GDB - Display Addresses

Tags: c, memory, assembly, gdb, disassembly

In a piece of code viewed in gdb such as the following:

```
0x8e4e <boot1main+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x8e50 <boot1main+3>:   push   %esi
0x8e51 <boot1main+4>:   mov    0xc(%ebp),%esi
0x8e54 <boot1main+7>:   push   %ebx
0x8e55 <boot1main+8>:   mov    0x10(%ebp),%ebx
0x8e58 <boot1main+11>:  sub    $0xc,%esp
0x8e5b <boot1main+14>:  push   $0x3
0x8e5d <boot1main+16>:  call   0x8bb6 <roll>
0x8e62 <boot1main+21>:  movl   $0x8f84,(%esp)
0x8e69 <boot1main+28>:  call   0x8b77 <putline>
```

What is the precise meaning of the addresses on the left? Are these where the assembly instructions are located on the machine? (i.e. 0x8e4e, 0x8e50).

The above piece of code was generated without having set up virtual memory yet. In fact, it represents some boot-loader code I am tracing through.

For a normal C program, are those addresses on the left virtual addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the address of the code you're looking at. And yes, for a normal C program on a "proper" OS, the addresses would be virtual.